# Calling SQL Server stored procedure from vb.net 2008 error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a SQL Server stored procedure from vb.net 2008. But I get the error

> Procedure or function 'Sp_Messages_Display' expects parameter '@MsgSno', which was not supplied.

Here is my code

```
Public Function Load(ByVal CnnStr As String, ByVal MsgSno As Long, ByVal Msg_Status As eMsgStatus) As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Com As ADODB.Command
    Cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cnn.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
    Cnn.ConnectionString = CnnStr
    Cnn.Open()
    Com = New ADODB.Command
    Com.ActiveConnection = Cnn

    With Com
        .CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "Sp_Messages_Display"
        .CreateParameter("@MsgSno", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adBigInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 4, MsgSno)
        .CreateParameter("@Msg_Status", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adSmallInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 4, Msg_Status)
        Load = .Execute(RecordsAffected)
        SqlError = Err.Description
    End With

    If Not Load.EOF Then
        With Me
            .MsgSno = Load.Fields("MsgSno").Value
        End With
    End If
    Com.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    Cnn = Nothing
End Function
```

Please help me where I am wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: You've tagged this as VB.NET: you would be better off using ADO.NET rather than the legacy ADO types.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add parameters to the `Command`, the `CreateParameter` only creates a new instance without adding it to the collection of the `Command`:

```
With Com
    CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "Sp_Messages_Display"
    .Parameters.Add("@MsgSno", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adBigInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 4, MsgSno)
    .Parameters.Add("@Msg_Status", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adSmallInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 4, Msg_Status)
    Load = .Execute(RecordsAffected)
    SqlError = Err.Description
End With
```

I now believe you are not using **VB.NET**, but **VB**, in that case this is the way to go from MSDN:

```
ccmd.parameters.Append ccmd.CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamReturnValue, , NULL)   ' return value
ccmd.parameters.Append ccmd.CreateParameter("InParam", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "hello world")   ' input parameter
ccmd.parameters.Append ccmd.CreateParameter("OutParam", adVarChar, adParamOuput, 20, NULL)   ' output parameter
```

Comment: how do i append added parameters.. i tried few, but doesnt work.. plz help. thanks

Comment: @srinivasan not sure what you mean; if you invoke `Command.Parameters.Add` as in my example above, they should be appended to the `Command` and it would be ready to be executed.

Comment: If you want to create a parameter first and then append it, you can use `CreateCommand`, store the result in a variable and then add it using the `Parameters.Add` overload that takes a `Parameter` object.

Comment: i dont find add method in parameters object. so i used create parameter... i use vb.net 2008... Error 1 'Add' is not a member of 'ADODB.Parameters'.

Comment: Are you sure you are using VB.NET? This is an example, it uses the `Append` method (not .NET): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675860(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: got it yaar, pbm is with the references i have included in the project.. parameters.append only works with activex 2.8 objects which lists in com componenets (vb6 components).. but in .net components there is way to use create parameter method... we need to find it out... anyways thanks a lot for your precious time... :-)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation to [`CreateParameter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677209(v=vs.85).aspx):

> This method does not automatically append the Parameter object to the Parameters collection of a Command object.

You need to add the parameter you have created to the collection.

Comment: how do i append added parameters.. i tried few, but doesnt work.. plz help. thanks